# The irreducibility of $t^4 + 2$ over $\mathbb{Z}_5$

Tags: galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I'm reading Stewart's Galois Theory Third Edition Example 3.23, where we are proving that $f(t) = t^4 + 15t^3 + 7$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ is irreducible by showing its mapping to $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is irreducible.

First, the polynomial gets mapped to $t^4 + 2$ over $\mathbb{Z}_5$. Then Stewart says if it is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}_5$, then either it has a factor of degree 1, or it is a product of two factors of degree 2 (understandable). Then he claims "The first possibility gives rise to an element $x \in \mathbb{Z}_5$ such that $x^4 + 2 =0$" -- here I'm not following how this gives rise to such an equation for which we could check whether the factor of degree 1 is possible...Many thanks for help!

Comment: If there is a linear factor $t - a$ so that $t^4 + 2 = (t - a)p(t)$, then

$$a^4 + 2 = (a - a) p(a) = 0$$

in $\mathbb{Z}_5$

Comment: As discussed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/353233/11619) this polynomial remains irreducible over the bigger field $\Bbb{F}_{125}$. The answers there also show the irreducibility over $\Bbb{Z}_5$ because the main claim of the other question follows from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(copied from my comment)

If there is a linear factor $t - a$ so that $t^4 + 2 = (t - a)p(t)$, then

$$a^4 + 2 = (a - a) p(a) = 0$$

in $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

Comment: How do we know that $a$ must be in $\mathbb{Z}_5$?

Comment: @ShiyueLi Where else would it be? You're working over $\mathbb{Z}_5[t]$.