# Find $n$ such that $f$ is reducible or give a proof.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

Let $f = X^4 + 2$ and let $n$ be odd. I am looking for a proof or a counter example to show that $f$ is irreducible or reducible over $\mathbb{F}_{5^n}$.

Answer (score 2):

First show that $X^4+2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb F_5$. Then use the result proved in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/353491/121097).